# problem with get_option in dashboard

Tags: options

I have created simple plugin which transfer the html code from text-area in dashboard to front-end page where function defined in the plugin is being called to render the front page.
However i have problem with reading the option. i.e. .Saving works ok, but reading do problems.

the example code for the field to be saved and read.

```
<textarea name="bn_notice_F" type="text"
    value="<?php echo get_option('bn_notice_F'); ?>" ><?php
    echo get_option('bn_notice_F');
?></textarea>
```

Saving the option works, but when I read `get_option` the function adds some text, eliminates the html marks etc.

For example when saving:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rlZRtQkfK04"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It saves correctly, but when displaying on the dashboard I get:

```
</iframe>" ><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rlZRtQkfK04" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

any clue why? is there any sanitizing or sth similar ? if so how to to pass and save raw text from text-area , and read to text-area raw code?

thank you for help

UPDATE
The plugin is set as

```
add_submenu_page('options-general.php', __('b_Notice'), __('b_Notice'), 'delete_plugins', 'b-notice', array($this, 'settingsPage'));
```

and there is form to save and read text for options.

Then i have form code

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('bn'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('bn'); ?>
             <label for="bn_enabled_S1">Side Notice</label>             
             <input type="checkbox" name="bn_enabled_S1" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'bn_enabled_S1' ) ); ?> />           
             <textarea name="bn_notice_S1" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('bn_notice_S1'); ?>" ><?php echo get_option('bn_notice_S1')?></textarea> 
            <?php submit_button(); ?>            
    </form>
```

and then the function

```
 public function settings(){
    register_setting('bn', 'bn_enabled_F');
    register_setting('bn', 'bn_notice_F');
}
```

Thank you for looking at code.

Comment: Can you post the full code? The code that updates the option isn't present. Also when you say the dashboard, are you referring to the admin area in general, or specifically to the dashboard page inside the admin area? Or is this a settings page? It isn't clear, please update your question with as much information as possible, not just the bit that outputs the textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `value=""` attribute, for example `<textarea value="<iframe>">` is invalid HTML, and the browser will do its best to try and fix the markup. That's why you're getting strange results

So instead, remove the `value` attribute. You'll also want to escape with `esc_textarea` to prevent malicious code breaking out of the text area

Comment: @GregSkala if it answers your question can you mark it as the correct answer?